# Chef: Vault Hashicorp ruby gem

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to use the vault gem on my chef recipe.

I'm importing it on my `metadata.rb

```
gem vault
```

Then on my recipe `default.rb`

```
Vault.configure do |config|
  config.address = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
  config.token = "token"
end

secret = Vault.logical.read("secret/stripe")
stripe_key = secret.data[:api_key]
```

But an error raises:

```
uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Chef::Recipe:0x00000000036346a8>>::Vault
14>> Vault.configure do |config|
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do `require 'vault'` on the top of your `default.rb` file. That way the `Vault` constant will be made available to your recipe.